# Jest giving TypeError

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I am writing a test to mimic the click event on my component.
My Component has below line

```
<Button name="1" clickHandler={this.handleClick} />
```

which am testing with

```
it('Test Button component', () => {
    it('Test click event', () => {
      const mockCallBack = jest.fn();  
      const button = shallow((<Button onClick={mockCallBack}>1</Button>));
      button.find('button').simulate('click');
      expect(mockCallBack.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
    });
  });
```

But when I run the test it gives me an error

```
TypeError: this.props.clickHandler is not a function
```

Can anyone please help me as how should I mimic the click.

Comment: Can you share more of the code?  (It sounds like the component expects the handler to come in on the `clickHandler` prop)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code (I did not test it), bur basically use `.simulate()` directly on the wrapper and use `.toHaveBeenCalled()`.

```
it('should test Button component', () => {
    it('shoud test click event', () => {
      const mockCallBack = jest.fn();  
      const button = shallow((<Button onClick={mockCallBack}>1</Button>));
      button.simulate('click');
      expect(mockCallBack).toHaveBeenCalled()
    });
  });
```